# Grafana: How to create a different gauge for each $volume?

Tags: grafana

I'm new to Grafana. I'm trying to create a bunch of gauges, one for each PVC I have in Kubernetes. Looks like this right now:

[image]

The query is:

```
(kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes{persistentvolumeclaim="$volume"} - kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes{persistentvolumeclaim="$volume"}) / kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes{persistentvolumeclaim="$volume"}*100
```

It works fine with one volume, but when I try to allow multiple, it just says "no value" whereas I want multiple gauages.

Pretty sure this is doable, but I'm not sure how. Do I have to change the query somehow to repeat for each volume or what?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Panel has a `Repeating` config in the `General` section, where select your `volume` variable. Then also select `All` in the variable. At the end you may hide dashboard variable `volume`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the query has to use `=~` to be able to fetch multiple data points.

```
(kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes{namespace="$namespace",persistentvolumeclaim=~"$volume"} - kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes{namespace="$namespace",persistentvolumeclaim=~"$volume"}) / kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes{namespace="$namespace",persistentvolumeclaim=~"$volume"}*100
```